# Etale cohomology and restricted direct product

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, etale-cohomology

[migrated from math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727896/etale-cohomology-and-restricted-direct-product]

$\newcommand{\h}{\operatorname{H}}$
Let $k$ be a global field, $A$ an abelian variety over $k$, and $\mathbf A$ the ring of adeles of $k$. One defines the *Tate-Shafarevich group* of $A$ by 
$$
  Ш(A) = \ker\left(\h^1(k,A) \to \prod_v \h^1(k_v,A)\right)
$$
where $\h^1(-)$ is etale cohomology, and we interpret $A$ as a sheaf on the etale site of $k$. In fact, the image of $\h^1(k,A)$ lands inside of the smaller group 
$$
  \prod_v' (\h^1(k_v,A), \h^1(\mathfrak o_v,A))
$$
(restricted direct product). This makes sense because for almost all $v$, $A$ has good reduction at $v$.

> My question is, do we have 
>   $$
>   \h^1(\mathbf A_k,A) \simeq \prod_v' (\h^1(k_v,A), \h^1(\mathfrak o_v,A))?
> $$

In that case, we could define $Ш(A) = \ker(\h^1(k,A) \to \h^1(\mathbf A_k,A))$. 
I'm a little worried because $\mathbf A_k$ is pretty horrible when considered as a commutative ring, so its etale site will probably not be easy to manage.

**Edit:** Just so its clear, this was inspired by Poonen's lectures at the most recent AWS.

Comment: Would it help to phrase this geometrically?  Presumably, the homomorphism you want takes an $A$-torsor over $\mathbf{A}_k$ and base-changes to an $A$-torsor over each $k_v$.

Answer (score 6):

You don't define what is meant by ${\rm{H}}^1(\mathfrak{o}_v, A)$ (it is an abuse of notation, as $A$ lives over $k$ or $k_v$, not $\mathfrak{o}_v$), but the only definition which comes to mind at a good place (namely, cohomology over $\mathfrak{o}_v$ with coefficients in the abelian scheme Neron model at $v$) vanishes due to Lang's theorem over the finite residue field and the smoothness of torsors over $\mathfrak{o}_v$ for a smooth group scheme.

In other words, the proposed alternative definition is nothing more or less than the *usual* definition, in view of the fact that for *any* finite type smooth connected commutative group scheme $A$ over a global field $k$ and any class $\xi \in {\rm{H}}^1(k,A)$, for all but finitely many $v$ the local restriction $\xi_v \in {\rm{H}}^1(k_v,A)$ vanishes. (The proof of such vanishing at almost all $v$ is a pleasant exercise with the torsor interpretation of such H$^1$'s and standard "spreading out" arguments.)

Since $\mathbf{A}_k = \varinjlim_S (k_S \times \prod_{v \not\in S} \mathscr{O}_v)$ where $S$ varies through the finite sets of places of $k$ (containing the archimedean places) and $k_S := \prod_{v \in S} k_v$, the compatibility of etale cohomology with respect to arbitrary directed systems of rings gives that $${\rm{H}}^1(\mathbf{A}_k,A) = \varinjlim_S (\prod_{v \in S} 
{\rm{H}}^1(k_v,A) \times
{\rm{H}}^1(\prod_{v \not\in S} \mathscr{O}_v, A_S))$$
where $A_S$ is the abelian scheme Neron model of $A$ over the ring $\mathscr{O}_{k,S}$ of $S$-integers for sufficiently big $S$.

So the content of the question then reduces to showing that if $R = \prod_{v\not\in S} \mathscr{O}_v$ and $G$ is a smooth finite type $R$-group scheme with connected fibers then ${\rm{H}}^1(R, G) = 1$. The elements in this H$^1$ are represented by algebraic spaces over $R$ that are fppf $G$-torsors (hence $R$-smooth with geometrically connected fibers).  Using this geometric interpretation and a concrete description of finite etale $R$-algebras (and finiteness of the residue fields of the local factor rings $\mathscr{O}_v$), the vanishing is proved on pages 613--614 (and top of page 615) of the paper "Finiteness theorems for algebraic groups over function fields" in Compositio 148 (2012).

Comment: Fantastic answer! This is exactly what I was hoping for.